# How does one build 'where' clause dynamically when projecting to Dto?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When projecting results of the joins onto DTO using EF, how does one dynamically build a "where" clause? In NHibernate it was really easy to do this, but I cannot figure out how to do this with Entity Framework.
Just to clarify, I don't want to filter objects, I want sql to be built.

This is what I am trying to do.

```
private async Task<List<InvoiceInfo>> GetDataWithManualProjection()
{
    var query = (from i in db.Invoices
                 join cj in db.CustomerJobs on i.CustomerJobID equals cj.ID
                 join c in db.Customers on cj.CustomerId equals c.ID
                 let invoice = i
                 let customer = c
                 let customerJob = cj
                 select new InvoiceInfo()
                {
                    Number = invoice.InvoiceNumber,
                    Balance = invoice.InvoiceBalance,
                    PrePay = customer.PrepaymentBalance
                })
                .AsQueryable();

                BuildWhereClause(filter, query);

               return await q.ToListAsync();
}



private void BuildWhereClause(InvoicesFilter filter, ref IQueryable<Invoice> q)
{


    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.ClientName) == false)
    {
        switch (filter.ClientNameFilterOptions)
        {
            case ClientNameFilterOptions.Contains:
                q = q.Where(x => x.ClientName.Contains(filter.ClientName));
                break;
            case ClientNameFilterOptions.EqualTo:
                q = q.Where(x => x.ClientName == filter.ClientName);
                break;
            case ClientNameFilterOptions.StartsWith:
                q = q.Where(x => x.ClientName.StartsWith(filter.ClientName));
                break;
        }
    }

    if (filter.InvoiceBalance.HasValue)
    {
        var invoiceBalance = filter.InvoiceBalance.Value;
        switch (filter.InvoiceBalanceComparisonOperator)
        {
            case ComparisonOperator.EqualTo:
                q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceBalance == invoiceBalance);
                break;
            case ComparisonOperator.GreaterThan:
                q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceBalance > invoiceBalance);
                break;
            case ComparisonOperator.GreatherThanOrEqualTo:
                q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceBalance >= invoiceBalance);
                break;
            case ComparisonOperator.LessThan:
                q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceBalance < invoiceBalance);
                break;
            case ComparisonOperator.LessThanOrEqualTo:
                q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceBalance <= invoiceBalance);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.Address) == false)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.CustomerJob.BillingAddress1 == filter.Address);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.City) == false)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.CustomerJob.BillingCity == filter.City);
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.ZipCode) == false)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.CustomerJob.BillingZip == filter.ZipCode);
    }

    if (filter.InvoiceFrequency != InvoiceFrequency.NotSet)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceFrequency == filter.InvoiceFrequency);
    }

    if (filter.InvoiceStatus != InvoiceStatus.NotSet)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.Status == filter.InvoiceStatus);
    }

    if (filter.StartDate.HasValue)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceStartDate >= filter.StartDate.Value);
    }

    if (filter.EndDate.HasValue)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.InvoiceEndDate <= filter.EndDate.Value);
    }

    if (filter.PaymentMethod != MethodOfPayment.NotSet)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.MethodOfPayment == filter.PaymentMethod);
    }

    if (filter.InvoiceNumbers.Any())
    {
        q = q.Where(x => filter.InvoiceNumbers.Contains(x.InvoiceNumber));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.LineItemDescription) == false)
    {
        q = q.Where(x => x.LineItems.Any(l => l.InvoiceDescription.Contains(filter.LineItemDescription)));
    }

    if (filter.HasCCOnFile)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to build `Where` based on `invoice`, `customer` and `customerJob` (before projection)?

Comment: Yes, which works fine, if I hardcode "where" clause. But I want to dynamicaly build it based on the InvoiceFilter settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your private method needs to have the following syntax:

```
 private  IQueryable<InvoiceInfo> BuildWhereClause(Expression<Func<InvoiceInfo,bool>> filter,
                               IQueryable<InvoiceInfo> q)
 {
    return q.Where(filter);
 }
```

And you don't need to call `AsQueryable` method at the end of your query

### Update

If you want to apply the filter to your entity and not to the projection, then you need to compose your query in several steps, eg:

```
IQueryable<Invoice> query= db.Invoices;
BuildWhereClause(filter,ref query);
var result= (from i in query
             join cj in db.CustomerJobs on i.CustomerJobID equals cj.ID
             join c in db.Customers on cj.CustomerId equals c.ID
             select new InvoiceInfo()
            {
                Number = i.InvoiceNumber,
                Balance = i.InvoiceBalance,
                PrePay = c.PrepaymentBalance
            });
```

Also, there is not need to use `let` clause in your query, every time you are using it, an extra projection will be applied.

Comment: But what am I going to do with InvoiceInfo in the method, InvoiceInfo is a projection. I can not use it to build where clause.

Comment: But where do you want to apply the filter, you're applying it to the result of your projection according to your example, right?

Comment: No, I don't want to query over objects, I want sql to be built.

Comment: That's not going to query over object, that query will be executed in your server. You're composing a query, just the filter is going to be applied to the projection

Comment: How does that compile?  You `return q.Where(filter);` from a `void` method.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, thanks for pointing me out the syntax error, that is a typical copy/ paste issue ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the `Invoice` filter in advance and use the resulting `IQueryable` inside the LINQ query:

```
var invoices = db.Invoices.AsQueryable();
BuildWhereClause(filter, ref invoices);

var query = (from i in invoices
             join cj in db.CustomerJobs on i.CustomerJobID equals cj.ID
             ...
```